# RabbitMq direct queue that does not accumulate in "Ready" state?

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp

I would require a queue that does not accumulate in "Ready" state.

That is, if there is a subscriber to the queue, pass the messages from the exchange directly to it, and if there is no subscriber, just waste the messages, do not accumulate them in "Ready" state.

I know that an exchange of type `fanout` does this, but I want to be able to use the routing key and a `fanout` exchange ignores the routing keys. Moreove my scenario is not a broadcast one, it is 1 publisher and 1 (sometimes absent) subscriber.

Is it possible to have a direct exchange to which the queue does not accumulate messages in "ready" state if there is no subscriber?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok I think I must declare the queue with `auto-delete` to `true`

and set the `mandatory` bit to `true` on the `BasicPublish` calls

it seems to work so far...

Comment: also make the queue "exclusive" if only the one consumer that created it, should consume from it